# How to push elements into an empty array which is not initialized as empty array globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have variable as,

```
let Details
```

and an array as,

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3]
```

I want to push arr1 elements into Details as an array,

for this I tried,

```
for(let i =0;i<apple.length;i++){
    Details = []
    Details = Details.push(apple[i])
}
```

I know I can declare Details as empty array as,

```
let Details = [] ,
```

But I have other conditions for **Details**, so I cannot initialize **Details** as array globally or use another variable.

Is there any way I can insert value inside **Details** as array without initializing it as empty array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `if` statement to check if the variable is falsy like `undefined` or `null` and then set the variable to an empty array if true

```js
let details;
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (!details) details = []; 
  details.push(arr1[i])
}

console.log(details)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me....but why do I need to check whether details is true or false,

why is it not working if I write as :

let details;
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  idetails = []; 
  details.push(arr1[i])
}

Comment: Because on each iteration, `details` would be reinitialized to an empty array. also, `details.push()` returns `undefined`. So you running `details = details.push(...)` will also set `details` to `undefined`.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you also accept the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, also I tried to accept this answer but stackoverflow doesnot allow to accept the answer for at least 10 mins.so with in 2 mins I will be accepting the answer. :)

Comment: @a.mola just a detail: `Array#push()` returns the arrays new `length` after the push, not `undefined`.

Comment: @SivaPradhan I made a mistake with my explanation. `details.push()` returns the length of the array. Thanks to Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Destrucuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
arr = [1,2,3]
Detail = [...arr]
console.log(Detail)

Detail2 = []
Detail2 = [...Detail2, ...arr]
console.log(Detail2)

Detail3 = [4,5]
Detail3 = [...arr, ...Detail3]
console.log(Detail3)

Detail4 = [-1,0]
Detail4 = [...Detail4, ...arr]
console.log(Detail4)
```